# Elasticsearch : Search text by skipping words between in shingles

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, shingles

When I search for a text "submarine sinks ships" I want the search ranking to prioritize the matches for "submarine ships". 
But in my index of shingles size 2, the text will be indexed as  {'submarine sinks', 'sinks ships'} but will not be indexing the first & third letter{'submarine ships'} as one bigram & eventually will give rank to the existing bigrams. How do I make that search work in this case?